# Why does VSCode's Jsonnet Language Server think this line is wrong?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonnet

The following line has existed in my jsonnet code for a long time. The code executes as expected. I just started using VSCode and installed the Jsonnet Language Server but now the server seems to think the line is problematic. Why?

the code

```
local containers = import 'containers.libsonnet';
```

the error message

```
couldn't open import "containers.libsonnet": no match locally or in the Jsonnet library paths
```

Comment: Did you find any fix?